# How to best query across both Oracle and SQL Server databases for large tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, data-warehouse

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that also queries tables in the same database and in a different Oracle database. This is for a data warehouse project that joins several large tables across databases and queries them.

Is it better to copy the table(with ~3 mil records) to the same database and then query it, or is the slowdown not significant from the table being in a different database? The query is complicated and can take hours.

I'm not necessarily looking for a specific answer, informed opinion and/or specific further reading are also very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the actual query? Offhand, I'd say it will be faster to let the remote database handle what it needs to and return the results instead of copying the whole table over first. Depending on the size of each row, 3 million records can be a lot to transfer over the network.

Comment: Get the data from Oracle the way you don't have to do any additional mofdification (e.g. aggregation) with this data only, as Spivonious already pointed out. Then perform any calculation required. Regarding the query itself: it's rather unusual to have a query that might take hours to complete... There seems to be more to it than simply get some data from Oracle...

Comment: Are you servers physically seperated by a large distance?  I've had a 3 hour running query that was taking record off a machine in one city and combining it with data from a server half a continent away.  My solution was to run a query on the primary server to identify the rows it would need in the remote server, copy those rows only to the primary server (into a temp table) and then run the full query using that temp table instead.  Might not be applicable here...but it may possible to grab a small subset of the 3 million records you need and copy that to the primary server.

Comment: Querying across databases is called 'federation' and is one approach to reporting across systems. If you are frequently joining this remote (Oracle) table to a local table, and you also need to process/add extra info to the Oracle table then I would suggest undertaking an ETL exercise to load the data locally. I work with a system that replicates about a dozen different systems (SQL Server, Oracle, and others) into an Oracle database, adds reference data and performs all joins locally. There is additional administrative overhead in this approach but its often worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I **always** prefer stage layer, or somebody calls it integration layer.
In your case (on blind) it's perhaps best solution to:

1. Copy table once
2. Create a sync step (Insert/Update) based on primary key(s)
3. Schedule step 2
4. Run your query

If there is some logical data-integrity rule, you can create second step by simple SQL based on timestamps.